# How to start Appium server programmatically before the first scenario executed? (Using Cucumber and JUnit)

Tags: java, junit, automated-tests, cucumber, appium

I want to start Appium server before the first scenario and then after the last scenario is executed, I want to close it.

But I cant do it...

Currently it starts the server before each scenario, and it makes my tests takes longer time...

Here is my code:

1. This is my appiumServer class:

```
package appiumserver;

import io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService;
import io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder;
import java.io.File;

public class AppiumServer {

    static AppiumDriverLocalService server;
    static String mainJSpath = "C:/Users/emin/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js";

    public static void start() {
        if (server == null) {
            AppiumServiceBuilder builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
            builder.withIPAddress("127.0.0.1")
                    .usingPort(4723)
                    .withAppiumJS(new File(mainJSpath))
                    .usingDriverExecutable(new File("C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe"));

            server = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(builder);
            server.start();
        }
    }

    public static void stop() {
        if (server.isRunning()) {
            server.stop();
            server = null;
        }
    }

}
```

2. This is my Hooks class:
   (I am invoking start() method here...)

```
package hooks;

import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;
import io.cucumber.java.Scenario;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import utilities.Driver;

import static appiumserver.AppiumServer.start;


public class Hooks {


    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        //This will start the Appium Server...
        start();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown(Scenario scenario) {
        if (scenario.isFailed()) {
            final byte[] failedScreenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) Driver.getDriver()).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
            scenario.attach(failedScreenshot, "image/png", "failed-scenario-" + scenario.getName());
        }
        Driver.closeDriver();
        //stop();
    }


}
```

I tried @BeforeAll and @AfterAll annotations, but didn't work...

Comment: The answer is to use the `@BeforeAll` and `@AfterAll` annotations. If that doesn't work, you should ask a question about that. Do read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example